# How do you Undelete a user account via Google's API?

Tags: google-api

I'm trying to get the Google Apps user account Undelete API function to work, but keep getting a "400 Bad Request" error. I also tried using it from the official API demo page, but got the same results. (However, their Admin Console web interface can Undelete accounts with no problems.) Has anyone else seen this, and were you able to work around it?

Undelete demo page (you'll need to be logged in as a Google Apps admin):
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/undelete